# Lagrange multiplier problem in book

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier, nonlinear-system

$f(x,y,z)=xyz$

$g(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2+3z^2-6$

Then:

$\begin{cases}yz=2x\lambda\\xz=4y\lambda\\xy=6z\lambda\\x^2+2y^2+3z^2=6\end{cases}$

According to book's solution if any $x,y,z$ is equal to $0$, then $x=y=z=0$, which contradicts the last expression.

However, isn't possible to have $x=y=\lambda=0$ and $z\neq 0$ so last expression can be true?

Comment: the solution of the book is wrong

Answer (score 2):

The constraint must be binding, otherwise you could increase the objective function indefinitely. It follows that $\lambda \neq 0$, and then the argument works.

Comment: So, in general, for calculus course, you think $\lambda \neq 0$ for all exercises?

Comment: @JoãoPedro No. Only when the constraint is binding. Here is an example of when that would not be the case: $\max_x -x^2$ subject to $x \leq 1$.

Comment: How do I know if the constraint is binding?

Comment: @JoãoPedro One way is to solve the problem without it and show that it would be violated.